# Does redux evaluate all listeners to the store on any update to the store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, easy-peasy

From what I can tell, redux will notify all subscribers to the store when anything in the store changes no matter if it's a subscription to a deeply nested leaf or a subscription to the top level of the state.

In an application where you follow the guiding principle:

> many individual components should be connected to the store instead of just a few... [[docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#how-well-does-redux-scale-in-terms-of-performance-and-architecture)]

You could end up with lots of listeners and potentially performance issues?

Disclaimer: I understand that the selector functions will only cause a re-render if the result of the selector function changes. I understand that just because the listener function is evaluated, doesn't mean the subscribing component will re-render. I understand that evaluating a selector function is comparatively cheap to a react component rendering.

However, I just would like to confirm that this is indeed how redux works?

e.g. given the following example listener

```
const result = useSelector(state => state.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k)
```

if we update some other value down some other path, not relevant to the above listener e.g.

```
const exampleReducer = (state) => {
   return { ...state, asdf: 'asdf' }
}
```

From my understanding, all listeners, including the example above, will be invoked.

For context, my actual use case is I'm using https://easy-peasy.now.sh/ which is built on redux. To be clear, I don't have any current performance issues in production related to binding too many listeners. However, each time I attach a listener via the `useStoreState` hook, I'm wondering whether I should minimize binding yet another listener to the store.

Also if you're curious, inspired by this thinking, I implemented a state tree which only notifies [the relevant listeners](https://github.com/mfbx9da4/observable-state-tree).

Perhaps this is a premature optimization for a state library... but if so why? Is there an assumption that applications using redux will have simple and fast selectors and that the application bottleneck will be elsewhere?

Comment: That came to my mind when I shifted from Angular to React

Comment: What do you mean with `listener to a deeply nested value`? You can [subscribe to store](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) (not recommended), use react-redux hook [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) (recommended) or react-redux [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) if you can't use hooks because you still use class components.

Comment: made an update does that clarify ?

Comment: People will tell you that you're worrying too much about performance, but depending on the use case you could be asking an extremely important question.  For example, if you were implementing a DAW like Ableton Live from scratch, triggering high-fps rerenders via a centralized immutable state store would probably be a performance disaster no matter how much you try to optimize it.  Many web developers have no experience with use cases like this, so they're barely aware of the potential drawbacks to Redux.

Comment: I happened to ask [this same question over on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/o8lnty/new_redux_docs_usage_deriving_data_with_selectors/h36glqz) and Mark also kindly [responded with some of the details of what happens for each `useSelector` subscription](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/o8lnty/new_redux_docs_usage_deriving_data_with_selectors/h36juty). The TL;DR is that running a selector is going to be a bunch cheaper than having a component rerender, but it's likely possible to still have too many `useSelector` calls at some point (unclear what that limit is).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer and author of React-Redux v7.  The other couple answers are actually pretty good, but I wanted to provide some additional info.

Yes, the Redux store will always run all `store.subscribe()` listener callbacks after every dispatched action.  However, that does not mean that all React components will re-render.  Per your `useSelector(state => state.a.b.c.d)` example, `useSelector` will compare the *current* selector result with the *previous* selector result, and only force this component to re-render if the value has changed.

There's multiple reasons why we suggest to "connect more components to read from Redux":

- Each component will be reading a smaller scoped value from the Redux store, because there's less overall data that it cares about
- This means that fewer components will be forced to re-render after a given action because there's less of a chance that this specific piece of data was actually updated
- Conversely, it means that you don't have cases where one large parent component is reading many values at once, is always forced to re-render, and thus always causes all of its *children* to re-render as well.

So, it's not the number of listener callbacks that's really the issue - it's how much work those listener callbacks do, *and* how many React components are forced to re-render as a result.  Overall, our performance tests have shown that having *more* listeners reading *less* individual data results in fewer React components being re-rendered, and the cost of more listeners is noticeably less than the cost of more React components rendering.

For more info, you should read my posts on how both React and React-Redux work, which these topics in extensive detail:

- [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/)
- [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/)
- [ReactNext 2019: A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/)

You may also want to read [the Github issue that discussed the development of React-Redux v7](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1177), where we dropped the attempt to use React Context for state propagation in v6 because it wasn't sufficiently performant enough, and returned to using direct store subscriptions in components in v7.

But yes, you're worrying too much about performance ahead of time.  There's a lot of nuances to how both React and React-Redux behave.  You should actually benchmark your own app in a production setting to see if you actually have any meaningful performance issues, then optimize that as appropriate.

Comment: "*always causes all of its children to re-render as well*" - shouldn't React's virtual dom diffing prevent that?

Comment: "Virtual DOM diffing" _is_ the process of re-rendering. Please read the linked "Guide to React Rendering Behavior" post, which describes all this in detail.

Answer (score 4):

> From what I can tell, redux will notify all subscribers to the store when anything in the store changes no matter if it's a subscription to a deeply nested leaf or a subscription to the top level of the state.

Yes, all subscribers are notified. But notice the difference between **Redux** and its **React-Redux** utils.

> You could end up with lots of listeners and potentially performance issues?

With **React-Redux** you subscribe to a store (of **Redux**) by having a selector (`useSelector`/`connect`).

By default, every subscribed component in **React-Redux** will be **rerendered** if its subscribed store portion changed, to handle it you pass a selector which bailout the renders.

But for **Redux**:

- The notification itself handled by Redux (outside React).
- Redux doesn't handle the "deeply nested leaf" (React Context API handles it as part of React-Redux implementation) it doesn't handle locations - it just calling callbacks.
- The notifications are [batched in a while loop](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/a9235530f4799dd4b2acb3cc65e9caf32efbc44b/src/utils/Subscription.js#L74) **outside** the React context (optimized).

```
// There is a single Subscription instance per store
// Code inside Subscription.js
notify() {
  batch(() => {
    let listener = first
    while (listener) {
      listener.callback()
      listener = listener.next
    }
  })
}
```

---

In conclusion, if it's not a case of premature optimization:

> Premature optimization is spending a lot of time on something that you
> may not actually need.  “Premature optimization is the root of all
> evil” is a famous saying among software developers.

All subscribers in **Redux** will be **notified**, but it's not influencing the UI.

All subscribed **components** will be rerendered only if the portion of the state changed (enhanced with selectors) - influencing the UI, therefore thinking about optimizations, you should **subscribe to comparable portions of the store**.

Comment: Yeah I agree that premature optimization is the root of all evil but redux doesn't really know how the store will be subscribed to. I am also fully aware that the component / UI will not be rendered if the result of the selector does not change. What is a good way of approaching whether too many listeners could be a performance bottleneck?

Comment: If there is a bottleneck, too many listeners will be the last cause of it. Again, you really looking for premature optimization. Listeners ARE NOT REDUCERS as explained in the answer, you don't have any code in them, its like having a for loop of lets say 1000 items, its fast enough, try tackling real bottlenecks

Comment: Where did I say that listeners are reducers? It depends what the listeners are doing if all they do is `state => state.a` then yes it's like a for loop with 1000 items. If each listener is doing some costly thing then it will be expensive...

Comment: I agree that this would most likely not be a bottleneck for most applications when combined with selectors. However, if you're building a state library it seems natural to optimize only firing relevant listeners rather than memoizing the previous result of all listeners.

Comment: State=>state.a is not a listener, it's a selector, I explained what listener is in the answer, listener are related to Redux not react-redux

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about react components that get state from redux (tags in your question) using react-redux. The react-redux tag is missing but that is what is mostly used and used in the [standard create react app template](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#create-a-react-redux-app).

You can use the [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook or [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object) with connect. Both more or less work the same way.

If an action causes a new state to be created then all functions passed to useSelector or mapStateToProps will be executed and the component will be re rendered only when they return a value that is not referentially the same as previous value. For mapStateToProps it works a little different as it does a [shallow equal](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js) comparison with the value returned.

You can use [reselect](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) to compose selectors and re use logic to get certain branches and/or adapt the returned data from the state and to memoize the adapted data so jsx is not needlessly created.

Note that when a component re creates jsx that does not mean the DOM is re created since React will do a virtual DOM compare of the current jsx with the last one but you can optimize by not re creating jsx at all with memoized selectors (using reselect) and having pure components.

The worst thing you can do is pass a handler function that is re created on every render since that will cause jsx to be re created because props changed and DOM to be re created since the handler function causes virtual DOM compare to fail, for example this:

```
{people.map((person) => (
  <Person
    key={person.id}
    onClick={() => someAction(person.id)}
    person={person}
  />
))}
```

You could prevent this from happening using the useCallback hook from React or create a PersonContainer that will create the callback `() => someAction(person.id)` only when re rendered.

Comment: Have updated question with more context of my actual use case

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer the question. I'm asking about the internals of how redux works, not best practices for avoiding rerenders.

Comment: @david_adler Using easy peasy doesn't change anything and using more selectors/containers that use useSelector is still the better option because the performance loss would outweigh the maintainability (getting state and passing it around through props creates tightly bound components). Not sure how you'd use observable state tree but I would not advice storing [non serializable](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) values in state. It'll break persist middleware for sure and possibly many others.

Comment: @david_adler Internals of how it works is in the answer, please read it carefully: `If an action causes a new state to be created then all functions passed to ... and having pure components.` Since your question mentioned concerns about performance I added the main culprit of performance degradation, passing handlers that cause actual DOM updates, not virtual DOM compares.

Comment: @david_adler It looks like your concern is react-redux calling many `useSelector` callbacks when a dispatched action causes a new state to be created. If a selector callback does expensive calculations then reselect will alleviate some of the expense by memoizing values and not execute the expensive code if it is not needed: `const selectSomething = creaeteSelector([selectSimple1,selectSimple2],(one,two)=>expensive code)`

Comment: yeah so basically an extra level of optimization and memoization is needed as out of the box redux will just evaluate all listeners. In practice, like you say, there are normally other bottlenecks rather than too many listeners.

Comment: @david_adler Correct, as Dennis also stated; the selectors will usually not be the bottleneck. Preventing expensive operations and re renders with memoized selectors is just one of the advantages, composing query logic is probably the most important one. A query can be `state=>state.something` but can be `state=>calculate insurance premium`, obviously you don't want the latter to be defined on the fly in your component with an arrow function because you are running the risk of duplicate logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answer to the original question BUT related enough to be mentioned.

Sometimes on very complicated React systems Redux notifications may actually cause trouble. If every other optimization technique seems exhausted you might want to hack Redux itself a little bit.

See:
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=redux-notification-enhancer

This enhancer allows to reduce amount of renders in React by reducing notifications coming from Redux. It can be achieved by enabling throttling and/or marking certain actions as passive (updating state but not causing render). Both optimization techniques will increase complexity along with performance - use with care.