# How to set radio button value when redirecting to another page in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a quiz app with next js. I have two buttons (next and previous).I select a answer of question from radio button. But when I go to next question and select the answer and then go to the previous question, the selected value of radio button gets unchecked. How can I keep selected that value.How can I get selected value when redirect between next and previous questions?

Comment: You'd have to pass the value to the next page, using GET (easiest way), POST (would require user to submit a form [push a button]), or cookies/session variables of some sort.

Comment: Potentially related information on one option https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811853/125981

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is common in ReactJs development. You have to save the state, when navigating to a new page, otherwise it is discarded. Two possible solutions are using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the built in [useContext](https://dev.to/ms_yogii/usecontext-for-better-state-management-51hi).

Comment: I have two buttons (next and previous). And if i click on next button, and select the answer and then click on previous button, it unselect my answer. How can I keep selected that value?

Comment: Just do exactly what is written in the useContext guide. This will solve your problem. There is no easier solution, if you are navigating between pages.